# When slide the Manipulate's bar too fast the value is too few

Tags: manipulate

A code can trace the kinetic point.But when you slide the bar too fast,you cannot get smooth curve like fllowing.

```
a = 2; p = {{0, 0}};
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], FaceForm[Pink], 
    Disk[{a \[Theta], a}, a]}, {Blue, PointSize[Medium], 
    BezierCurve[
     AppendTo[p, 
      point = {a (\[Theta] - Sin[\[Theta]]), a (1 - Cos[\[Theta]])}]],
     Point[point]}}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 6 \[Pi] a}, {-2, 3 a}}], {\[Theta], 0, 6 \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

The reason is the `Manipulate` produce too less value of `Theta` that the `BezierCurve` isn't precise:

```
a = 2; p = {{0, 0}};
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], FaceForm[Pink], 
    Disk[{a \[Theta], a}, a]}, {Blue, PointSize[Medium], 
    Point[AppendTo[p, 
      point = {a (\[Theta] - Sin[\[Theta]]), a (1 - Cos[\[Theta]])}]],
     Point[point]}}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 6 \[Pi] a}, {-2, 3 a}}], {\[Theta], 0, 6 \[Pi], 
  1/1000}]
```

[image]

So how to make the `Manipulate` produce more value of `Theta` during the slider being slided.

Comment: A `Manipulate` with only one slider is pretty much equivalent to an `Animate`, and with frames that are slow to render I would then simply use `ListAnimate` to pre-render everything. I only use `Manipulate` when two ore more parameters need to be varied simultaneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few things that need to be changed in your code.

First you need to wrap the `BezierCurve` with Dynamic and `TrackedSymbols` to prevent continues updating of `AppendTo`.

Second you need to sort `p` so that when slider move back the `BezierCurve` is appropriate.

```
a = 2; p = {{0, 0}}; Manipulate[
 Graphics[{{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], FaceForm[Pink], 
    Disk[{a \[Theta], a}, a]}, {Blue, PointSize[Medium], 
    Dynamic[BezierCurve[
      Sort@AppendTo[p, 
        point = {a (\[Theta] - Sin[\[Theta]]), 
          a (1 - Cos[\[Theta]])}]], TrackedSymbols :> {\[Theta]}], 
    Point[point]}}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 6 \[Pi] a}, {-2, 3 a}}], {\[Theta], 0, 6 \[Pi]}]
```

Apart from that, if you are looking just for graphics then why not simply use `ParametricPlot` ?

```
a = 2;
Manipulate[
 Show[{Graphics[{{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], FaceForm[Pink], 
      Disk[{a t, a}, a]}, {Blue, PointSize[0.02], 
      Point[{a t - a Sin[t], a - a Cos[t]}]}}, Axes -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 6 \[Pi] a}, {-2, 3 a}}], 
   ParametricPlot[{a \[Theta] - a Sin[\[Theta]], 
     a - a Cos[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], -.01, t}, 
    PlotStyle -> Blue]}], {t, 0, 15 a}]
```

In this case I would suggest you use the following method:

```
a = 2; 
p = {{0, 0}}; 
Manipulate[
     Graphics[{{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], FaceForm[Pink], 
        Disk[{a \[Theta], a}, a]}, {Blue, PointSize[Medium], 
        BezierCurve[
         p = Sort@
           Table[{a (t - Sin[t]), a (1 - Cos[t])}, {t, 0, \[Theta], .1}]],
         Point[Last@p]}}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
      PlotRange -> {{-2, 6 \[Pi] a}, {-2, 3 a}}], {\[Theta], 0, 
      6 \[Pi], .1}]
```

Comment: Better than my code.But when I slide it too fast for the first time,the effect is bad still.

Comment: @yode, what are you trying to get? is it the plot only or the plot and the list `p`?

Comment: The qeustion have posted that method with `ParametricPlot` before this edit.But in some case ,the equation(or parametric equation) isn't easy to confirm.So I try to avoid use the `ParametricPlot`.All the same,thanks for your advice.

Comment: +1 The second solution is fantastic! Not only fast but I very much like the removal of the curve when the disk rolls back.